# Magento soap login failed php

Tags: php, magento, soap, soap-client, magento-1.8

I am trying to get connected with Magento.

```
$WSDLUrl1 = "http://mysite/index.php/api/?wsdl";   
$proxy = new SoapClient($WSDLUrl1);
$sessionId = $proxy->login('soapusername', 'apikey');
var_dump($sessionId);
```

i can print the

```
$proxy
```

but failed to get

```
$sessionId
```

version -Magento 1.8

Created soap user and assign the admin role with all module permissions already

Error says

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server Error in
C:\wamp\www\ondemand\test.php:41 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient-
>__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://mysite...', 'urn:Mage_Api_Mo...', 1, 0)
#1 C:\wamp\www\ondemand\test.php(41): SoapClient->__call('login', Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\ondemand\test.php(41): **SoapClient->login('soapusername', 'apikey')**
#3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\ondemand\test.php on line 41
```

Please help..

Comment: Check logs of your API, your SOAP server crashed and returned Internal Server Error.

Comment: @Naktibalda - Thanks
I am not logging it anywhere.
Now i have tried reading soapFault via exception handling i.e try catch block i got 

"Internal Server Error"
No idea what's wrong

Comment: Your client code is correct. If it is Magento SOAP service, check magento logs.

Comment: I have enabled logs via Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes

I don't see any log file in folder var/log/

I have give permissions also.

Answer (score 0):

Without more error log details I can't say for sure what the issue is, but I had similar results when trying to access an API for a Magento EE 1.12.0.2 site.  It worked fine in my local instance, but not on the remote server.  In my case I was getting the following in my error log...

```
FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/html/php.fpm" aborted: error parsing headers: duplicate header 'Content-Type'
```

The cause of this was due to the `setHeader()` in the `run()` method in the file **app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Xmlrpc.php**. The cause of which is explained in more detail here... http://www.magegyver.de/duplicate-content-type-header-on-api-responses/

They also developed a small extension that you can add to correct this... https://github.com/MageGyver/ApiImprovements